Translation of 'EF.Property<Guid?>(f.ISBN, "Id")' failed on a string functional key field
Assume a class like this:
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Author { get; set; } = default!;
}

Id is the technical PK, ISBN is the unique functional key which we're querying on.
public Book Get(string isbn)
{
    var result = _db.Books
        .SingleOrDefault(book => book.ISBN.Equals(isbn));

    ...
}

Doing that query call I get this error on the SingleOrDefault line:

Message=Translation of 'EF.Property<Guid?>(f.ISBN, "Id")' failed.
Either the query source is not an entity type, or the specified
property does not exist on the entity type.

The generated migrations code looks like this:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "BOOKS",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "RAW(16)", nullable: false),
        ISBN = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        NAME = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        AUTHOR = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
    },

Question: The ISBN is not a Guid at all, it's a string. Why is this failed translation happening?
Is there somehow interference from the Id field?

To me that looks like somehow the ISBN property has been mapped to the Id column? I'd check all possible sources of configuration. Also double check the table column type etc ... maybe also migrations.

@Fildor Migrations is a good point, I have added the generated definition.

Do you do other configuration than Attributes on the Entity?

what happens when you try book => book.ISBN == isbn ?

Parse isbn to Guid first. After that use it in your query:
var guid = Guid.Parse(isbn); var result = _db.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.ISBN == guid);

@OlehIvanitskyy But ISBN is not a Guid. It's a string. A string that's not a representation of a Guid, on top of that.

@Fildor, oh sorry. I see

@kbd could you show what you have in OnModelCreating related to Book table

@OlehIvanitskyy kbd is the OP. :D You need a coffee .... haha

@Fildor omg, sorry again. I will back in 10 minutes with mug of coffee :D

Do you maybe have a global query filter? Or is this not a correct representation of your actual problem? It's really weird to have f.ISBN as the instance parameter in the EF.Property call.
